# MLPRegressor problem with attribute loss_curve_

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to plot the loss_curve by using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

def plotCurves(Xtrain,ytrain,Xval,yval):
    solver=["lbfgs", "sgd", "adam"]
    for i in solver:
        mlp=MLPRegressor(activation='relu',max_iter=1000,solver=i)
        mlp.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
        pred=mlp.predict(Xval)
        print (mlp.score(Xval,yval))
        pd.DataFrame(mlp.loss_curve_).plot()
```

However, when I run my code the following error appears:

```
'MLPRegressor' object has no attribute 'loss_curve_'
```

and in the Anaconda IDE version 1.9.7 it appears this method when I am coding.

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the [stochastic solvers](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L34) will expose a `loss_curve_` attribute on the estimator after fit, so in your first iteration it fails with the `lbfgs` solver. You can verify this with the following:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
​
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=5)
​
solver=[
    "lbfgs",
    "sgd",
    "adam"
]
​
for i in solver:
    mlp = MLPRegressor(activation='relu',solver=i)
    mlp.fit(X,y)
    print(hasattr(mlp, "loss_curve_"))
False
True
True
```

If you want to access this attribute, you'll want to stick with either the adam or sgd solver.