# Plot training and validation accuracy and loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am new to Python and trying to plot the training and validation accuracy and loss for my MLP Regressor, however, I am getting the following error, what am I doing wrong?

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validation_split'

```
mlp_new = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(18, 18,18),
                       max_iter = 10000000000,activation = 'relu',
                       solver = 'adam', learning_rate='constant', 
                       alpha=0.05,validation_fraction=0.2,random_state=0,early_stopping=True)

mlp_new.fit(X_train, y_train)
mlp_new_y_predict = mlp_new.predict((X_test))
mlp_new_y_predict

import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
history = mlp_new.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.1, epochs=50, batch_size=4)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085779/typeerror-fit-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-test)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely can find a `validation_split` arg in the keras model `.fit()` method.
But:
The model you are going to use here is not that one.

Check the documentation below, *Methods* section:
method `.fit(..)` has only two args: `X` and `y`.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.fit

Comment: I understand thank you. Then how how do you suggest I plot the training and validation accuracy and loss for my MLP Regressor?

Comment: Seems it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187854/mlpregressor-problem-with-attribute-loss-curve